# Use same base files for different projects in WebStorm 10

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, webstorm

How can I use same base files(js, css, less and pictures) for different projects in WebStorm 10 ?

I tried to find something under settings, but could not find anything useful...

Comment: You mean -- you create some project template with files and folder structure and you want to use it for new projects? That's not possible -- IDE does not support such project skeletons. Have a look at [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) -- PhpStorm can create new projects using that tool.

Comment: That's what I meant.Thank you.